# Being judged and blocked on chat before having right to speak a single word

Tags: discussion, etiquette, chat

EDIT : Lots of people have mentioned that the *personal situation*  part of the question is not necessary. Thus, on request, I have removed it.

---

Question :
*As a general principle* (not only here on SO), is it fair to be **publicly mentioned on chat** by a moderator (example : `@User : You are denied access because you did this wrong in the past...`), and **not** being able to answer a single word (because channel access has been denied) ?

Even if the moderators have the best reasons to deny access, is it legally acceptable to mention publicly someone (and claim unproven things) who cannot answer a single word?

*I suggest that the "access denial notice" should be done in private, but not publicly if the user has no right to correct the potential defamation.*

---

Second question : can we focus more on etiquette when access denial is done? in order to be in accordance to:

> Do I have to be nice? Yes. We expect community members to treat each
>   other with respect … even when they don't deserve it.

Comment: I have to agree, that guy acted *way* out of line.

Comment: That's a very rude comment, but it's still his chat room so he decides who goes in.

Comment: *his* chatroom is a part of a bigger site named StackOverflow which has an etiquette, which is part of a biggest entity called *civilization*, which has etiquette as well

Comment: @Basj Having an etiquette means that we are free to criticize, but the internet's freedom should still be respected.

Comment: So you haven't spoken to them at all outside of the room or invited them to private rooms etc?

Comment: I'm in that chat, he cursed at you because you were spamming him and others with private chat room requests after your request was denied and explained. You don't need to be an all star for access but you do need to demonstrate basic Android ability to keep the chat room useful and spam free for the people who use it.

Comment: While the chat room moderator may have been rude, is it really necessary to extrapolate the question to "a general principle in life"? You can build your case without egregious language and bold. (And I see you've rolled it back. Color me not surprised.)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think the *real* effect is that everyone now sees both sides of the story and believes that the OP is just as at fault as the person who told him to "f*ck off".

Comment: @basj Can you please rollback the question? You've invalidated the current answers. Make your [meta-tag:feature-request] a new question.

Comment: @remyabel Huh? You (and others) complained when this question was polluted with personal / emotional aspects (at least 10 comments showed it). I removed them and kept only the real question.

Comment: @basj I said [**please, don't do that**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280444/being-judged-and-blocked-on-chat-before-having-right-to-speak-a-single-word?noredirect=1#comment130633_280448). Others have pointed out that you had a valid claim (that you were bad-mouthed and unable to respond), but as the discussion has reflected, that claim is no longer valid and your question should remain in its previous state to avoid invalidating the current answers.

Comment: *You* said this here, but lots of people have said the contrary, and I now agree: the emotional part is not important. And the fact someone said to me *@Basj go the fuck away* is really not important in this question.

Comment: and the original question got original answers which are only valid if the original question remains in tact. you can start a second question as a [meta-tag:feature-request] for the remaining concerns. If I were you (which i'm not, so take this as a suggestion) I would revert this back and start a new question on a new thread.

Comment: It's funny how people asked me to remove the "butthurt" aspect (I had counted many occurences of this word, that I previously did not know, as a non native english speaker), and now that it's done... the contrary is asked. End of the epiphenomenon for me.

Comment: we asked you to separate the two concerns. Bastardizing the original question wasn't the idea (at least not from me). If you really do feel strongly about it and want fresh feedback on a "fresh" question it will need to be asked in a new question. simple as that. you can't on main site ask a question about PHP then edit it to use Node after answers are posted. Same applies here, changing the scope of the question is not cool.

Comment: Just delete the question and start over. You'll probably even get a free hat (maybe there's one for deleting a question like for an answer). Win win. This question has votes that are locked in, the question and all answers need edits now so that meaningful votes are even possible to be realized.

Comment: @rlemon It's not a scope change at all. Please remember my initial version of the question, you will see exactly these questions : first one about not being able to answer on a public channel where my name was dropped with some comments of some users,   second about etiquette of the moderators (the `@Basj Go the fuck away` part). Only the personal part is removed. I suggest that we stop these endless comments now.

Comment: Then consider you've accepted an answer which doesn't address the private issue. The entire focus on the question is changed. This thread is now useless.

Comment: @SterlingArcher The context? It's quite easy and short as I was muted and never spoke ever in this channel. The context was : access request, denial of access, mention of my name publicly, then I wanted to request the removal of my name publically mentioned, then as I could not speak, the only way was to ask a mod in private. I did with one, he did not answer, he adviced to ask another one. I did.  Then public mention `@Basj go the ... away` (removed from transcript now). That's 100% of the context, it's here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20494894#20494894

Comment: As a conclusion, I learned something yesterday in a *sociological aspect*: first random visitors voted this topic (they had 100% of the context, they had the transcript, and as pointed in my last comment, there's nothing more than this), it went up to *+10 upvotes*. Then the *"Come on friends, help me on this topic"* effect (some channel transcripts prove it ;)) arrived, and yes, having social network friends helps: you are stronger when you are 10 and can say "Let's go together on this topic". This was a very interesting lesson :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Knowing now what I do from answers provided by [Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280450/1079354) and [codeMagic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280448/1079354), I can say a few more things in regards to the scenario.

I still don't think that the language received (now removed from the post) was appropriate, even if it was during a relatively heated moment; at the same time, if the history of the chat room has led them to enforce a lockdown such as the one they have to preserve some sense of sanity, then I can't say I oppose it.  Given the emphasis on discussion quality and the very real occurrence of beginners trampling over the established courtesies and policies in place for that chat room, it makes sense that they have to take those steps to preserve their own individual community.

I neither fault them for their subsequent actions (save for the remark), nor do I find that their prohibition of people for their behavior on SO is awkward, weird, or xenophobic.

Original (partially redacted) response below.

---

The remark you received was simply uncalled for.  I'd report that to a community moderator post-haste to get something done about it.

As for being denied access in the chat - that, I'm not sure of.  I would presume that a chat moderator has the privilege to allow or disallow whomever they choose for whatever reason they choose, <s>but it's kind of awkward/weird/xenophobic to deny someone that hasn't chat within the room before.</s>

They have their reasons stated [in their channel rules](http://room-15.github.io/) as to how to gain access.  Maybe they didn't view your contributions favorably?  I can't answer that definitively; it's really up to them to allow or deny you access.

Comment: thanks, I've reverted my downvote to an upvote and removed my previous comment.

Comment: Ah, xenophobia. The fear of [xenomorphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_%28creature_in_Alien_franchise%29). Quite an understandable phobia!

Answer (score 26):

Let's see if we can do this without it getting out of hand...

**The denial**

I am the one who denied access **twice** within a minute. We have people request access multiple times after being denied in a short period of time and it gets frustrating.

**The accusation**

The "accusation" that I made false claims against you was inaccurate. I was talking about a different user who kept being flagged for spamming rooms...nothing to do with you at all. I did go into the private room you set up and explained this and even apologized for the misunderstanding.

**Bad words and bothersome chatsters**

Yes, he didn't need to use the "fuck" word with you but, again, I'm sure he was frustrated as I was, that you requested access multiple times then asked me to join a private chat then him. We are professional in there but we also have a laid back manner. He doesn't usually say stuff like that but you shouldn't have kept asking for access and inviting us to rooms.

**I should take some blame on this one**

In full disclosure, I told you to try him but I honestly didn't think you would take it seriously. I was trying to mess with him when I did it...lesson learned. A lot of people are bothered when you go into a chat and invite someone to a private chat.

**The real issue at hand?**

If that is the main issue (the "public denial/approval") then a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for a way to do it privately would be in order, though I don't see that happening and it should be a  new post not editing this one. If you aren't really interested in that and just feel publicly shamed or something then just let it go. We don't sit around a campfire and laugh about all the people we denied that day. It really isn't a big deal at all. Some people in there have been denied a few times before gaining access.

Comment: can confirm. random people inviting me to a private chat never bodes well.

Comment: Asking to go in a private chat would have been the *only way* to tell you: "I accept your decision, you are free to accept who you want, **but please can you remove the public claims about me for which I cannot even answer publicly**. It was the only point.

Comment: Can also confirm. Situation taken out of context.

Comment: The context? There is no context here! Or more accurately : the context is very short, as long as I could not tell anything.

Comment: @Basj I wasn't in the room and don't care to surf the transcripts, but codeMagic did state that those comments were not directed at you but a legit spammer. there was a user posting a spam link in like 12 rooms recently. flags... flags everywhere.

Comment: @Basj And I did eventually go in there. Even though it's annoying, I usually give the user a chance to at least say one statement to me about it. I didn't feel like it this time (at first) and that is fine. I, or anyone else here, is never obligated to answer anyone in a post, chat, or otherwise.

Comment: @codeMagic Don't misunderstand me: I did not complain about you. I accept your choice and your words. I just point a situation for which I am mentioned publicly with `1) Go the fuck away` without having said a word ever on this channel, and without any possibility to tell you "Could you please remove this content with my name?" . Nothing more than this.

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding you. What you are missing is that I have said several times (even in the private chat with you) and rlemon tried to drive the point home, I was not talking about you. Except the denial request which I also explained in our chat. We tell you why you are denied so you understand and can know what to change if you want.

Comment: The question was not about you and me or anyone else. **The question is more general : is it normal to mention publicly someone who cannot speak a word and could not ever?**

Comment: @Basj that is currently how the system works. you can join the room and view messages but cannot speak. There is no private messages for users, so your denial conversation is public no matter what, even in a secondary room.

Comment: @Basj you have a legitimate claim here but have clouded it with a lot of misinformation of how things rolled out. Had you initially presented it more accurately and complained about that part only I'm sure that community response would have been at least a little different.

Comment: @codeMagic As proposed by many people here, I suggest that I remove all the *personal part* of the question and only keep the neutral question. Do you agree?

Comment: IMO, if you have a real feature request in all of this, it should be opened in a new, coherent issue. Editing this one is probably a fruitless endevour

Comment: @Basj No, please don't do that. Others have pointed out that the irrelevant information (i.e., the "neutral question") clouded the original context. Misrepresenting what actually happened is what I meant by saying it was a [strawman](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280453/3920237). If anything, the egregious information is what led to the severe number of downvotes.

Comment: @remyabel codeMagic (who was the main person involved with me) said it could be beneficial (his comment was removed), as well as many other comments. I followed the advice.

Comment: @Basj Yes, but I believe I was wrong which is why I removed my comment. I guess I didn't realize how much you would change it. It makes everything else confusing with the amount that you have changed. I thought you were just going to do some tiny housekeeping on it. And I honestly wouldn't care but I do think there may be some value in this post.

Comment: @codeMagic Nearly everyone has pointed out that the personal aspect of this question made it bad (although many comments about that have been deleted). I thought it's more reasonable to eliminate the *personal part* : I have nothing against you, (and probably?) you have nothing against me. (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yeah, no we're fine. But I meant to make the feature-request as a new post if you really wanted. As @remyabel has pointed out, the answers will seem confusing and not so helpful now.

Answer (score 26):

This doesn't excuse the language, but [there's a bit of history with the Android chatroom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110603/how-can-we-chat-in-the-android-room/110688#110688). That and the more popular iOS chatrooms are locked because they became places where question-askers would go to harass more regular users, spam their questions, and even insult people who voted to close their poor questions. When the question bans came online, this got even worse. This [drove away more experienced Android developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78334/how-can-i-improve-my-chat-rooms-quality).

Thus, the Android room requires approval to participate in. This is an attempt to keep the signal to noise ratio at a reasonable level. Again, the same goes for several other chatrooms that experienced problems like this.

I'm not privy to the approval process for these chatrooms, but you can imagine that they might look for those who aren't as likely to dump questions there.

The negative reaction from the owner may have come from your use of a chat invite (which people get notifications for) to get their attention. Chat invites are regularly abused by people attempting to spam their questions to members of these rooms, so sometimes people have an allergic reaction to them.

Comment: I would like to go out of the *personal situation story* (I don't care at all about these people who accepted/did not accept me), and to have more an answer more on my general question : is it fair mention publicly someone who is not able to say a single word?  In another situation, let's imagine defamation is made: is it normal that the person cannot reply?

Comment: @Basj If that was really your question, none of the other information was needed.

Comment: The fact you were badmouthed and were unable to reply to that was not cool. It was not a crime but it was bad etiquette. The problem is that you have clouded that concern with a lot of irrelevant information claiming they were totally unfair to you without reason when in fact there was a reason - you were mass pinging them with room requests and inviting them to private rooms. Had you only requested access once and was denied and that was it _like your question suggested_ there might have been have been room for action , however we now know that was not the case.

Comment: @AndrewBarber A question needs a reproducible example, no? Why did I mention other information? Yes of course I was disappointed to be publicly mentioned that way. That was reaction *à chaud*.

Comment: @basj: Is there anything really substantial going on here, or is this just butthurt on both sides?

Comment: @Basj The attempt to "generalize" the question is not at all necessary and is dangerously close to being a [strawman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).

Comment: I think the question would be better quality if it was an actual question instead of an attempt to gain sympathy by airing your butt hurt in public.

Answer (score 8):

So, here's your question:

> Is this the kind of behaviour promoted for SO chat channel moderators?

Answer: No, not really.

---

That clears this all up, right? If so; there's no need to read further.

If not;

It seems to me what should have happened here is to take a step back as soon as things got less than pleasant. If it was something really important that had happened, flag for a moderator. If not, just walk away.

Honestly; *regardless of any details*, what other answer makes sense, here?